# What's Spring's default queue size with a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor?

Tags: spring, multithreading, queue, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I'm using Spring 4.3.8.RELEASE with Java 7.  I want to create a thread pool to execute tasks so I have set up the following in my Spring contxet

```
<bean id="myThreadFactory" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.CustomizableThreadFactory">
    <constructor-arg value="mythread-"/>
</bean>
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="threadFactory" ref="myThreadFactory"/>
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50" />
</bean>
```

So as not to crush machine CPU usage, I want to limit the amount of concurrent threads that can exist in the system (I assume that's what maxPOolSize does).  But I don't want tasks to get dropped.  If I add more than 50 tasks to my taskPoolExecutor, what happens to number 51?  More importantly, what is the default number of tasks that can be added before they start getting dropped?

Comment: The default is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` meaning unbounded. See https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html#setQueueCapacity-int-.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Setting `maxPoolSize` implicitly allows for tasks to get dropped.
However, the default queue capacity is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which, for practical purposes, is infinity.

Something to watch out for is that `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` uses a `ThreadPoolExecutor` underneath, which has a somewhat unusual approach to queueing, described in [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html):

> If `corePoolSize` or more threads are running, the Executor always prefers queuing a request rather than adding a new thread.

This means that `maxPoolSize` is only relevant when the queue is full, otherwise the number of threads will never grow beyond `corePoolSize`.
As an example, if we submit tasks **that never complete** to the thread pool:

- the first `corePoolSize` submissions will start a new thread each;
- after that, all submissions go to the queue;
- if the queue is finite and its capacity is exhausted, each submission starts a new thread, until there are `maxPoolSize` threads in the pool;
- when both the pool and the queue are full, new submissions are rejected.

Comment: I'm not quite tying together what your'e sayihng.  If the queue is infinity, it will never be full, right?  So if my core pool size is 10 and max pool size is 50, what hpapens when I add a 51st thread?

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide an example, does it help?

Comment: I think so.  So in my code, I didn't specify a value for the queue size.  So does that mean my maxPoolSize specificaiton is meaningless bcause the default size for the queue is infinite?

Comment: Yes, your pool will never run more than `corePoolSize` threads.

Comment: I think the third point should be corrected as "if the queue is finite and its capacity is exhausted, each submission starts a new thread, up to `maxPoolSize-corePoolSize`;"

Comment: @MikayilAbdullayev thank you for your comment, I've reworded that paragraph to make it clearer!

Answer (score 3):

**Note reg the different queue configurations available in ThreadpoolTaskExectuor.**

> Any BlockingQueue may be used to transfer and hold submitted tasks.
> The use of this queue interacts with pool sizing: If fewer than
> corePoolSize threads are running, the Executor always prefers adding a
> new thread rather than queuing. If corePoolSize or more threads are
> running, the Executor always prefers queuing a request rather than
> adding a new thread. If a request cannot be queued, a new thread is
> created unless this would exceed maximumPoolSize, in which case, the
> task will be rejected.

There are three general strategies for queuing:

1. ***Direct handoffs.*** A good default choice for a work queue is a SynchronousQueue that hands off tasks to threads without otherwise holding them. Here, an attempt to queue a task will fail if no threads are immediately available to run it, so a new thread will be constructed. This policy avoids lockups when handling sets of requests that might have internal dependencies. Direct handoffs generally require unbounded maximumPoolSizes to avoid rejection of new submitted tasks. This in turn admits the possibility of unbounded thread growth when commands continue to arrive on average faster than they can be processed.
2. ***Unbounded queues***. Using an unbounded queue (for example a LinkedBlockingQueue without a predefined capacity) will cause new tasks to wait in the queue when all corePoolSize threads are busy. Thus, no more than corePoolSize threads will ever be created. (And the value of the maximumPoolSize therefore doesn't have any effect.) This may be appropriate when each task is completely independent of others, so tasks cannot affect each others execution; for example, in a web page server. While this style of queuing can be useful in smoothing out transient bursts of requests, it admits the possibility of unbounded work queue growth when commands continue to arrive on average faster than they can be processed.
3. ***Bounded queues.*** A bounded queue (for example, an ArrayBlockingQueue) helps prevent resource exhaustion when used with finite maximumPoolSizes, but can be more difficult to tune and control. Queue sizes and maximum pool sizes may be traded off for each other: Using large queues and small pools minimizes CPU usage, OS resources, and context-switching overhead, but can lead to artificially low throughput. If tasks frequently block (for example if they are I/O bound), a system may be able to schedule time for more threads than you otherwise allow. Use of small queues generally requires larger pool sizes, which keeps CPUs busier but may encounter unacceptable scheduling overhead, which also decreases throughput. ( We have implemented this approach after multiple testes with tuning the queue size with core pool and maxpool size).

REF : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Answer (score 2):

Be aware of using the default `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` if many `@Async` tasks are executed.

As of Spring Boot 2.1 there is a default `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` with a default core size of eight threads. Although the max pool size is still infinity¹ and new threads can be theoretically created the queue size of this pool is infinity¹ as well.

The queue size will probably never hit and new threads will never be created.

At least set the queue size if `@Async` is used:

```
spring.task.execution.pool.queue-capacity=16
```

---

¹ infinity as in 2147483647 a.k.a. `Integer.MAX_VALUE`