# Unexpected error occurred invoking async method

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I am use spring boot maven project and implement @async for multi-threading request processing but i get below error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

2020-07-13 17:04:15.752 Unexpected error occurred invoking async method 'public void ProviderOperationImpl.proceedSMSResponse(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord) throws com.exception.CustomException'.
 20909 --- [response_executor_thread1] .a.i.SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler : Unexpected error occurred invoking async method 'public void ProviderOperationImpl.proceedSMSResponse(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord) throws com.exception.CustomException'.
```

And other one is:

```
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

2020-07-13 17:11:49.522 Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
 20909 --- [http-nio-9092-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:472) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:395) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:254) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:175) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_102]
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

And below my async configuration:

```
@Bean(name = "requestExecutor")
    public TaskExecutor requestThreadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(Integer.parseInt(25));
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(25));
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("response_executor_thread");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
```

I don't no why i am getting this error.

Comment: did you tried increasing memory of heap space?

Comment: @RahulKumar Thanks for reply, yes i give this parameter to my service
-Xms128m -Xmx500m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxHeapSize=500M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=500m -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the Queue Capacity in the requestExecutor bean . By default the Queue Capacity is Integer.MAX_VALUE.

[What's Spring's default queue size with a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44638056/whats-springs-default-queue-size-with-a-threadpooltaskexecutor)

```
  @Bean(name = "requestExecutor")
        public TaskExecutor requestThreadPoolTaskExecutor() {
            ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
            executor.setCorePoolSize(Integer.parseInt(25));
            executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
            executor.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(25));
            executor.setThreadNamePrefix("response_executor_thread");
            executor.initialize();
            return executor;
        }
```